# How to write count if group by officer?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I have to count every officer's cases where Survey='abc' and Activity='FI' and (outcome='C' OR outcome='D')

Here is my full SQL

```
SELECT officer, NULL,
    SUM(IIF(ISNUMERIC(mkt) = TRUE AND Survey='dasda' AND Activity='FI' AND Outcome = 'C', Totalmin, 0 ) / 60),
    SUM(Non), SUM(ICC), NULL, NULL, NULL, COUNT(IIF(Survey='abc' AND Activity='FI' AND (Outcome='C'or Outcome='D'), Totalmin, 0))
FROM [DB$]
GROUP BY officer " '
```

The problematic part is

```
Count(IIF(  Survey='abc' and Activity='FI' and (Outcome='C'or Outcome='D'), Totalmin, 0 ))
```

However ,for the result that i generated doesn't work. The count result is far more than the answer .

Comment: Please show us sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Because `0` is not null, it is counted.  Here are two options:

```
COUNT(IIF(Survey='abc' AND Activity='FI' AND Outcome IN ('C', 'D'), Totalmin, NULL))
```

or

```
SUM(IIF(Survey='abc' AND Activity='FI' AND Outcome IN ('C', 'D') AND Totalmin IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))
```

Comment: But in my perception , count() counts only (IIF) true case . Hence , count() should not count (IIF) false case (0) . Isn't ?

Comment: @Vito . . . Your perception is wrong.  `COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values, regardless of whether or not there is an `IIF()` expression.